# Format Factory equivalent in 14.04

Tags: file-format, format-conversion

I use Format Factory in Windows to convert media files in different format. Is there any good tool that can convert mp4 to mp3 in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

It's ages that I don't use Windows, but [someone in the Italian community](http://chiedi.ubuntu-it.org/questions/41374/file-converter-generico) asked the same exact question some time ago and in the end he was very happy with [Format Junkie](http://www.itworld.com/article/2698423/install-format-junkie-media-converter-in-ubuntu-14-04.html).

Unfortunately, it needs an external PPA. To add it and install the program you can use the following terminal commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install formatjunkie
```

Answer (score 0):

For the audio files you can use:

`sudo apt-get install soundconverter`

for the video files

`sudo apt-get install transmageddon`

These are simple tools from the default repositories, but they make the job done.